# Inverse of 4 by 4 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Usually when we want to find the inverse we row reduce a matrix along with the identity matrix on the right side until we're done and the inverse would be the one on the right side.

I'm not sure about how to find the inverse of this one though as the right side doesn't look like identity matrix. What approach should I use to find the inverse?

UPDATE: This is Full Question:

[Better layout here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B63bgZ0nsirhNmlKOXFnckxTQ00/view?usp=sharing)

suppose A and B are 4 by 4 matrices such that

A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 3 & -4\\ 6 & 4 & 8 & 10 \\ 3 & 2 & 5 & -1\\-9 & 5 & -2 & -2\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

And

\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 3 & -4\\ 6 & 4 & 8 & 10 \\ 3 & 2 & 5 & -1\\-9 & 5 & -2 & -2\end{bmatrix} B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

a) find A inverse

b) find B inverse

This is confusing cause they look the same

Comment: What are your trying  to do precisely? What are the roles of the two matrices? The second has no inverse.

Comment: How did the second matrix turn into a $3\times4$ matrix?

Comment: oops i missed 1 row

Comment: trying to find inverse. that's how it's layout out in the homework. matrix A = [ first one ] = [ second one ]

Comment: Visualise the 4 by 4 matrix as a composition of 4 2 by 2 matrices

Comment: @33ted Why would you write an equal sign between two matrices which are obviously unequal? I bet your class uses some sort of augmented matrix instead.

Comment: I don't know. i'm just copying how it looks like in the homework

Comment: @33ted It looks an awful lot like you've forgotten that exchanging rows is a row operation, if you're finding the inverse of a matrix using an augmented matrix.

Comment: @33ted I have a hard time believing your homework says says $A$ is equal to these two matrices and you are finding an inverse. *What* matrix are you finding an inverse to? the first one? both? one you haven't written?

Comment: the first one A

Comment: @33ted then the second one doesn't mean anything?

Comment: but why is it there?

Comment: I think the formatting of this question is quite confusing. Which one is A and which is B?

Comment: sorry i can't make it nicer. this is for now 'til someone can organize my layout https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B63bgZ0nsirhNmlKOXFnckxTQ00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I understand it now, there isn't an equal sign its A multiplied by this matrix yields the one on the right where as the roles are reversed in the second part. You just need to show it as multiplication instead of equality

Comment: ur right dan. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your attached picture it looks like you should have $$AK = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$KB = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ where $$K = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 3 & -4 \\ 6 & 4 & 8 & 10 \\3 & 2 & 5 & -1 \\-9 & 5 & -2 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$
(Not that A = K = B.)
So if you can find a matrix $C$ such that $$C \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = I_4$$ then $$(CK)B = C \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = I_4$$ so $CK = B^{-1}$.
And since $$C \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}C = I_4$$ $$A(KC) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}C = I_4$$ and $KC = A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the confusion.